# Javascript only works when assigning variable to function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project that uses bootstrap. In the project, some additional functionality was needed so that when a user selects a certain option from the drop down it hid/showed certain content. It look as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" id="state-text" onChange="test()" name="selected-state" >
      <!-- Select options here -->
</select>
```

Then I had the JS as follows:

```
function test()
{
  // Code here
}
```

Now this didn't work, and would throw an error that function test was not defined. However, when I repalced it with:

```
test = function test()
{
    //Code here
}
```

it worked as intended. I don't understand why one worked and the other didn't? Does it maybe have something to do with the other JS files that the bootstrap file is importing?

Comment: Is your function declared before or after HTML markup?

Comment: I tried it both ways, and the results were the same as above.

Comment: the 2nd way works because you created a global variable.

Comment: The problem with your code is not actually shown.

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid adding JS in the middle of your HTML. Try doing that instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#state-text').on('change', function () {
        //Code Here
    });
});
```

I am assuming here that you are using jQuery since it's a requirement for bootstrap. If not, let me know.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried to avoid adding in the extra JS calls. It didn't work which is why I ended up doing it the way above.

Comment: Do you have more than one element with `state-text` id ?

Comment: No, there was only the one.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged the question as jQuery here's a fiddle I made quickly

http://jsfiddle.net/nYmF8/

markup

```
<select class="form-control" id="state-text" name="selected-state" >
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="b">C</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$(function(){$('#state-text').on('change', function () {
    alert('changed value to  to '+$(this).val());
});});
```

maybe you forgot to put your jQuery in [the document ready function?](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)